# Installing laravel 4 via composer?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have composer installed and openSSL extension enable in PHP but I still get the error (I restarted wamp twice)

```
Afflicto@Afflicto-PC /cygdrive/e/wamp/www/wirezapp2
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel wirezapp --prefer-dist
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.0.5)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v4.0.5)
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: 100%

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "http://nodeload.github.com/laravel/laravel/zip/v4.0.5" file could not  
be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "  
ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-
url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress]
[--  keep-vcs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

The php.ini in wamp is different than that used by apache/wamp, so I had to enable the open ssl extension via php.ini found in wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/php.ini