# How can I download and install Laravel Framework 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new in php programming and I like to install the latest version of Laravel framework on my windows os. When I trying to download Laravel through composer, I receive error like this:

[Picture of error in downloading and installing Laravel 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXg3L.gif)

Where is problem? Why I can't download Laravel?
I'm so appreciate if anyone help me
And sorry for my English
Thanks guys

Comment: Where is vendor directory?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot already has the answer for you.
It says git is missing or not installed.

Make sure that git is installed properly, and try it again.

Comment: How can I make sure that git is installed properly? I'm so sorry for my questions because I'm new in php programming. Thanks

Comment: @SamsonDavidoff You're welcome. Git has nothing to do with PHP, but is a versioning system, it can download and upload code to a repository. It's used to download code from Laravel's repo. As you're new to this, try: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-on-Windows, and choose 1 of the 2 presented options on how to install git on Windows. You can check, if git is installed by typing `git -v` to the console. Both solutions should add the PATH for you.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that it can't find git. Simply installing it isn't enough. Make sure it's in your `PATH` variable.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows) is an answered question on how to add directories to your windows PATH:

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I downloaded git-hub and install it. I set PATH variable successfully. Now I recieved new error from composer installer:

[New screenshot from new error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of0BH.gif)

What is this? :-(

---

It solved. My problem was network connection
Thanks to all.

Comment: You could have edited your first question instead of "answering" it. Despite this the error message as well is at least *informative*. It says that there's a problem with an SSL certificate. Nowadays most of those things are done on secure lines, using TLS-certificates. One problem could be, that the signing server hast problems. But another hint I found is, your PHP version might be outdated. Try to update it.

Comment: @AlexanderTrust But I'm using php 5.6.14. Is it old for laravel 5?

Comment: It might or might not be. **But** you should examine the screenshot. What do you see there? Well your command was related to composer. Hence the error is related to composer. I found here at StackOverflow this solution that might solve your problem. I guess you too have a WAMP/XAMPP or whatever and the OpenSSL is not properly initiated. Regard this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606131/installing-laravel-4-via-composer and tell us if it helped.

Comment: I saw this topic. I'm using XAMPP. When I search in xampp folder just found one php.ini that is located in the php folder in path: "c:\xampp\php".

Comment: I don't understand why laravel website doesn't get the compress (zip or tz or anything) of his framework for download like Yii website or others! And where is problem on my operating system!!! :-(

Comment: Even I found laravel 5 on git-hub website and downloaded it. But it has many errors like the previous mode!

Comment: Remote diagnosis is always a bit problematic... Have you updated PHP once within your XAMPP? Because I once did this, and in the config I just said, use this version instead. Then I restarted the server and it used the new PHP version **but** I ran into errors, for example for maximum file upload because the updated php instance had a different configuration file. If you use the standard one, it should not be the problem then.

Comment: No I doesn't updated php manually. It's the version installed with xampp server on my machine. One note that for several days my internet connection has problem. For example I cannot use of google without anti-filtering!!! I don't found where is problem but it's possible that internet connection related to SSL errors in my composer! What's your look?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no clue right now. Though it's late (or early) here, where I live and I stayed up all night. And I cannot help you too much, because I cannot reproduce the errors. Foremost because I don't use windows. Hence it's is hard for me to find possible solutions. But I wish you all the luck, so you can resolve your problem soon. I had SSL issues myself two days ago, had to change a config file for a RubyOnRails project because one of the certificate servers was down at that time.

Comment: OK. I'm so sorry. I wish you all the best.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking out the date and time of your computer,
make sure it is updated to your current local time and date.